# Has anyone set the database on a remote server while the controllers sit on local/hosted system

Tags: database, mysql, server, aws

I host the MySQL server providing the database functions and the site itself on the same hosting platform (a semi-dedicated server).

I was wondering if I could improve expression engine performance if I separate the two spheres to two separate servers. That is, put the database on some super fast server on a remote database provision service. Maybe even AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/

Anybody got experience with this implementation?

Answer (score 0):

That may not have the effect that your after. Yes, having a separate DB server is a good thing! I run a load balanced Arcustech setup with 3 servers (2 app, 1db).
We also have New Relic running on the servers.  At a glance it shows me that PHP is what is using most of the processing power and has a significantly higher transaction time than the database. I would make your main web server the one that has most of the grunt first. Beefing up servers unless your seeing a huge bump in traffic maybe a bandaid to a website that may not be build as efficiently as it could be. Take a look at the template debugging and the stack trace before throwing money at extra servers. It can be all enlightening.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent response. I have always looked at expression engine and thought how it was the PHP transactions that would make it slow rather than the db itself.